# Unable to read csv file from assets

Tags: java, android, csv, opencsv

I am trying to read a csv file from the android assets folder. I have viewed other posts on this and it seems I have it set up as others do. I have tried `this.getAssets()` and passing the context to the method and using `context.getAssests()` Here is the code that I am using to read the file. And put the information into a database.

```java
try{
        AssetManager mng = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        InputStream is = mng.open("word_types.csv");
        CSVReader csv = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String[] s;
        while((s = csv.readNext()) != null){
            db.addWordType(Integer.parseInt(s[0]), s[1], Integer.parseInt(s[2]));
        }   
        csv.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        Log.e("File Read Error: ","" + ioe.getMessage());
    }

    for(int i=1;i<=12 ;i++ )
            Log.i(i+" = ", ""+ db.getWordType(i));
```

Here is what prints out in logcat:

```
E/File Read Error: (25767): word_types.csv
I/1 =     (25767): null
I/2 =     (25767): null
I/3 =     (25767): null
I/4 =     (25767): null
I/5 =     (25767): null
I/6 =     (25767): null
I/7 =     (25767): null
I/8 =     (25767): null
I/9 =     (25767): null
I/10 =    (25767): null
I/11 =    (25767): null
I/12 =    (25767): null
```

Comment: Pass `ioe` as the third parameter to your `Log.e()` call, so you can see the full stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized I had made a stupid mistake. Thank you [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) for telling me about printing out the stacktrace like that. I did not know about adding ioe as a third parameter. After viewing the stacktrace I realized that I spelled the assets directory wrong. I had assests.

Comment: Stack traces are your friends! :-)